# Store meta data for page persistence w/out bloating server with InProc cache data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, local-storage, session-variables, session-state

In ASP.Net MVC, I'm looking for the best solution to store chat window data (ex. name, id, a couple bool values, and maybe some other data) for a chat window users have when logged into my site. Currently I store some meta data in a session variable and that data gets loaded into every page when rendered.

**Concerns** - if the site gets a lot of traffic and nobody logs off, then the InProc cache, server side, will start to blow up! Won't it? I know I can set the timeout for each session but won't that log the user off after that time. Not sure if I want that...also I still end up with the problem of having tons of users on at once!

**Requirements** - If chat window is open with data and the user directs to another page, he/she should have the same chat window (same data) open when the new page loads.

**Alternatives to InProc Session variables** -  1. store the meta data in HTML 5 local storage. 2. ???

**What I don't want** - is to fetch the data every time a page load occurs, and store that data in the viewmodel, that seems very tedious and repetitive.

Comment: Could you use something like a Redis Cache (or equivalent nosql / key-value database) to store and access the data on the server side? Slower than in direct memory but not as heavy-handed as a RDBMS

Comment: but wouldn't I have to fetch the data on every page load?

Comment: Hmm true. Could you use that as a backup then maybe TempData to pass info from one request to another? If TempData is lost, hit the NoSQL cache

Comment: No, tempdata won't work because it only holds the data for a request. I need to have it over a session (while the user is logged in). Essentially I'm looking to fill a partial page in my layout that encompasses a chat box/window. So when it gets loaded and displayed either by sending a message or receiving one, I need to have my user data (name, id, image url) for the chat box. Otherwise I'd have to fetch it every time and that seems tedious and repetitive